# Skip PERSONAL.xlsb workbook while ListWorkbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code to List out all the open workbooks, since all my codes are in Personal.xlsb it also get listed, can anyone tell me an If condition to skip the Personal.xlsb from the list.

And also since Personal.xlsb dose not have  a "Data_Index" it tends to give an error for that too

```
Sub ListWorkbooks()
Dim Wb As Workbook
For j = 1 To Workbooks.Count
    Sheets("Data_Index").Select
    Range("H3").Cells(j, 1) = Workbooks(j).Name
For i = 1 To Workbooks(j).Sheets.Count

Next i 
Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: `If Workbooks(j).Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then` skip this workbook

Comment: @TimWilliams if `<>` shouldn't it be "do whatever you want" ?

Comment: @Stephinn you need to fully qualify the object name inside your for loop

Comment: <> do that stand for "not equal"

Comment: it did not work out.. still in the `personal.xlsb` not skiping the `workbook`

Answer (score 0):

**Revised Answer**

From reading your comments on other answers you need to also identify which of the open workbooks has a worksheet named Data_Index as well, which is why you were getting a subscript out of range (your code assumed that every workbook had a sheet named Data_Index.

This works for me when I test:

```
Sub ListWorkbooks()
Dim Wb As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim c As Range

'Identify which (if any) of the open workbooks has sheet Data_Index
'Note if more than one it will pick the last one it finds
On Error Resume Next
For j = 1 To Workbooks.Count
    Set sht = Workbooks(j).Sheets("Data_Index")
Next j
On Error GoTo 0

'Check at least one has the required sheet
If sht Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "There is no open workbook with a sheet named Data_Index", vbExclamation
Else
    'Set the destination for the first workbook name
    Set c = sht.Range("H3")
    For j = 1 To Workbooks.Count
        If Workbooks(j).Name = "Personal.xlsb" Then GoTo NextWb
        c.Value = Workbooks(j).Name
        For i = 1 To Workbooks(j).Sheets.Count
            ' Whatever you want to do cycling sheets
        Next i
        'Offset to the next row ready for the next name
        Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
NextWb:
    Next j
End If
End Sub
```

You could do this using arrays, but the above will do it for you.

Comment: its giving subscript out of range error for 5 th line

Comment: Revised the answer based on comments in other answer

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ListWorkbooks()
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    For j = 1 To Workbooks.Count
        If Workbooks(j).Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
            Workbooks(j).Sheets("Data_Index").Range("H3").Cells(j, 1) = Workbooks(j).Name
        End If

        'not sure what you want to do here
        For i = 1 To Workbooks(j).Sheets.Count

        Next i
    Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: the list used to get print in the first workbook "Data_Index" Sheet

Comment: Sorry I'm confused. Which is the first workbook you are referring to?
Since you said `Personal.xlsb dose not have a "Data_Index` ...

Comment: suppose i ve oppened 3  workbooks, then the `Personal.xlsb` (because it open with every excel file) is my first workbook, Book1 and Book2 are second and third respectively, which has the sheet  `Data_Index` in them

Comment: and for all `workbook` with sheet `Data_Index` the list of all open `workbook` files are to be print at `Data_Index :H3`

Comment: So Book1, Book2 s' `Data_Index` sheets will both have a list of open workbooks' name ?